# Razor CheckBoxFor conditionally check and un-check in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.checkbox

In my view I have,

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsExist, new { @id = "IsExist" })
```

In my **Model** I have IsExist value from DB. Either true or false.

Now how can I 'Check' or 'Uncheck' the option, based on the true or false value in IsExist.
I expected, on binding by default the check box takes the value of Model. Howeverr that is not happening.

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to check a checkbox :

```
if (Model.IsExist) {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsExist, new { @id = "IsExist", "checked" = "checked"}) 
}
```

Hope it's help

Comment: Thanks actually I was manually initializing those checkboxes in a Jquery. There I set it to null. Once I removed as per false or true the code will work.

Answer (score 3):

Here how i achieved it

```
@Html.CheckBox("VC",(item.isVC=="Y") ? true : false)
```

where my `item.isVC` has value "Y" or "N"

Answer (score 3):

Below snippet indicates an alternate way of having checkbox created and conditionally making it checked/unchecked. The following approach is also useful to get the value of checkbox by traditional approach using jquery.

```
@model myproject.Models.StudentModel


<div class="row">
   <label class="checkbox-inline">
     <input type="checkbox" name="selfStudy" checked="@Model.IsExist"><b>Self Study</b>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @RikinPatel, It would be great if you could try it first and then give your insights on it.

Comment: @Sheekanth I have added comment so may be there is some reason right? Check it here. https://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/y5vhko9z/1/

Comment: @RikinPatel, My answer is using MVC model to set **checked** attribute but your fiddle is using text true/false being set in html directly, it won't work in that way. Please check my approach [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a9cZne).